Is there an way to center align vertically in customtkinter?
I had this question, which I searched online, but seemed to only get the online GitHub docs for customTkinter.
I have this code that is straight out of the documentation, and I have only removed a few lines, but it works well otherwise. Here is the code:
import customtkinter


customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")  
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x780")
app.title("CustomTkinter simple_example.py")



frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_1.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, justify=customtkinter.LEFT)
label_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)



button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1)
button_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_1, placeholder_text="CTkEntry")
entry_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


checkbox_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=frame_1)
checkbox_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

radiobutton_var = customtkinter.IntVar(value=1)

radiobutton_1 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=frame_1, variable=radiobutton_var, value=1)
radiobutton_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

radiobutton_2 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=frame_1, variable=radiobutton_var, value=2)
radiobutton_2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

app.mainloop()

As you see here the frame expands when full screened and show something like this:
How it looks
And what I want to change is, as you can see all the widgets have been center aligned in the x axis but top align in the y axis is there any way to bring it something like this(Into the red box)
How I want it to look
I want all the stuff to be inside the red box. Without actually hardcoding the position, can I bring it down to vertically center align it with all the current properties.

you need 2 frames, the first one establishes the background and centers the second frame, its child frame should hold all the widgets, this way this second frame is centered.
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x780")
app.title("CustomTkinter simple_example.py")

# create frame1
frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_1.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

# create frame2
frame_2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_1, fg_color="transparent")
frame_2.pack(expand=True)


label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_2, justify=customtkinter.LEFT)
label_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_2)
button_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_2, placeholder_text="CTkEntry")
entry_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

checkbox_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=frame_2)
checkbox_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

radiobutton_var = customtkinter.IntVar(value=1)

radiobutton_1 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=frame_2, variable=radiobutton_var, value=1)
radiobutton_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

radiobutton_2 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=frame_2, variable=radiobutton_var, value=2)
radiobutton_2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

app.mainloop()

In the code the second frame background is transparent, you can change that.


If you want more control over the ratio of top to bottom space. Then use a grid layout for frame_1 and give the surrounding rows/columns a suitable weight
frame_2.grid(row=1,column=1) 

# configure frame1 grid
frame_1.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame_1.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame_1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_1.rowconfigure(2, weight=1) 


Simply use frame_2.pack(expand=True) instead of frame_2.grid(...), then don't need to call those frame_1.rowconfigure(...) and frame_1.columnconfigure(...).
